# Creating move logic for a chess game. Can't figure out how to prevent Pawn from moving back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chess

I wrote a test to prevent pawn from moving back.

```
test 'pawn back move is invalid' do
  pawn = @game.pawns.first
  pawn.moved = true
  refute pawn.valid_move?(pawn.x_coord, (pawn.y_coord - 1))
  pawn.moved = true
  refute pawn.valid_move?(pawn.x_coord, (pawn.y_coord - 2))
end
```

Here's what I have for my pawn model.

```
class Pawn < Piece

  def valid_move?(x_destination, y_destination)
    x_dist = (x_coord - x_destination).abs
    y_dist = (y_coord - y_destination).abs

   # if self.moved
   #    y_dist == 1 && x_dist == 0
   # else
   #    (y_dist == 1 || y_dist == 2) && x_dist == 0
   # end

   while Game.where(:color => 'white') do 
    if self.moved
      y_dist == -1 && x_dist == 0
    else
      (y_dist == -1 || y_dist == -2) && x_dist == 0
    end
   end
  end
end
```

The reason why it's negative is because of the way board is set-up from x-coord (0..7) and y-coord(0..7)...

So the one in hash will make the best go through and throw me a fail, but the new code I write completely throws things off. I have Game controller and Pieces controller. I am not too sure which one I should call.

Here is the error message I get in my terminal.

```
  1) Error:
PieceTest#test_pawn_back_move_is_invalid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Pieces:Module
    app/models/pieces/pawn.rb:14:in `valid_move?'
    test/models/piece_test.rb:118:in `block in <class:PieceTest>'

  2) Error:
PieceTest#test_pawn_move_is_invalid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Pieces:Module
    app/models/pieces/pawn.rb:14:in `valid_move?'
    test/models/piece_test.rb:110:in `block in <class:PieceTest>'

  3) Error:
PieceTest#test_pawn_move_is_valid:
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Pieces:Module
    app/models/pieces/pawn.rb:14:in `valid_move?'
    test/models/piece_test.rb:103:in `block in <class:PieceTest>'

  4) Error:
PiecesControllerTest#test_should_move_piece:
NoMethodError: undefined method `valid_move?' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/pieces_controller.rb:13:in `update'
    test/controllers/pieces_controller_test.rb:8:in `block in       <class:PiecesControllerTest>'

  5) Error:
PiecesControllerTest#test_should_not_move_piece:
NoMethodError: undefined method `valid_move?' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/pieces_controller.rb:13:in `update'
    test/controllers/pieces_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in     <class:PiecesControllerTest>'

40 tests, 70 assertions, 0 failures, 5 errors, 0 skips
Coverage report generated for MiniTest to /vagrant/src/chess/coverage. 123 /       133     LOC (92.48%) covered.
```

I was initially calling my Pieces controller, because of the color.

```
class PiecesController < ApplicationController
def create
end

def destroy
end

def update
  @piece = Piece.where(:id => params[:id]).first
  x_dest = params[:x_coord].to_i
  y_dest = params[:y_coord].to_i

  if @piece.valid_move?(x_dest, y_dest)
    @piece.move_to(x_dest, y_dest)
    render :json => :success
  else
    render :text => 'invalid', :status => :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def piece_params
  params.require(:piece).permit(:color, :x_coord, :y_coord)
end
```

end

Here is the games controller. 
    class GamesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create, :update, :show]

```
  def index
    @games = Game.all
  end

  def new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def show
    @game = Game.where(:id => params[:id]).first
    render :text => 'That game does not exist.', :status => :not_found if      @game.blank?
  end

  def create
    @game = Game.create(:white_user_id => current_user.id)
    redirect_to game_path(@game)
  end

  def update
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    if @game.white_user_id == current_user.id
      flash[:alert] = "You can't play against yourself!"
      redirect_to games_path
    else
      @game.update_attributes(:black_user_id => current_user.id)
      redirect_to game_path(@game)
    end
  end

  private

  def games_params
    params.require(:game).permit(:black_user_id, :white_user_id)
  end
end
```

But I switched over to game controller to test out... I am very lost and any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Doing TDD on a game in Rails is a formidable task. This is not an answer to your question, but I suggest: 1. Start with a much simpler app. Such as Conway's game of life: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life. 2. After that, choose a much simpler game, such as Tic Tac Toe. 3. I don't think it needs to be a Rails app. You can learn all about TDD and Ruby without the complexity of Rails. It can be a Ruby app that prints to the terminal. 4. Go through some tutorials on how to TDD a simple Ruby app.

Comment: FWIW, I think doing TDD is the best way to learn.

Comment: @BSeven Thanks for the tip! Yeah, I am a beginner and this is a small group project we are working on... and, to say the least, I am very lost. I'll try to work on that before I tackle this again. thanks!